# How to get a start month column in a calendar table?

Tags: sql, calendar

I have a calendar in SQL which shows every date between 2014-2020 and the Week each dates commences on.

I am looking to add a new column (if possible) that shows the 1st of the month for each date.

For example:

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?..

Comment: Create a view instead, no need to add that type a column to a table.

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe not the fastest solution, but it works (SQL Server 2014):

ALTER TABLE [calendar]
ADD monthstart datetime

update [calendar]
set monthstart=datefromparts(year([date]),month([date]),01)

If datefromparts is not supported, you can try:

ALTER TABLE [calendar]
ADD monthstart datetime

update [calendar]
set monthstart= CAST(CAST(year([date]) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(month([date] AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(01 AS varchar) AS DATETIME)